# Microsoft RedisSessionStateProvider No connection is available to service this operation: EVAL

Tags: asp.net, redis, stackexchange.redis

We have deployed Redis ([Windows port](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases)) and the [Microsoft Redis Session State Provider](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/tree/master/src/RedisSessionStateProvider) to our production environment. Recently, our application failed outright for all users and we had the following error (repeatedly) in our log:

> No connection is available to service this operation: EVAL;
>   SocketFailure on 192.168.1.10:6379/Interactive, origin:
>   CheckForStaleConnection, input-buffer: 0, outstanding: 5, last-read:
>   1s ago, last-write: 0s ago, unanswered-write: 1s ago, keep-alive: 60s,
>   pending: 0, state: ConnectedEstablished, in: 12044, ar: 0,
>   last-heartbeat: 1s ago, last-mbeat: 1s ago, global: 1s ago, mgr:
>   RecordConnectionFailed_ReportFailure, err: never; IOCP:
>   (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=28,Free=32739,Min=8,Max=32767), Local-CPU: unavailable

Looking through the StackExchange.Redis library (where this error originated), it became apparent that we should increase the 'operationTimeoutInMilliseconds' value for the Session State Provider in the web.config, so that StackExchange.Redis will give the connection more time to recover from any transient error before failing.

My question is: Are there any other steps we should be taking to minimize the risk of this reoccurring? We would like to avoid this service disruption again if at all possible.